# Getting Sum Of Numbers In Each Line Of File

Tags: c#, streamreader

i have a file that there is some numbers that i want to sum number one with number two in each line.here is numbers in my file:

```
-944 -857
-158 356
 540 70
 15 148
```

for example i want to sum -944 and -857 what should i do??
i did it like the code below to check whats the numbers and the output is -158 and 15(it doesnt show -944 and 540 !!!):

```
        StreamReader ar = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\arash\Desktop\problem1 (3).in");
        while (ar.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            string[] spl = ar.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            MessageBox.Show(spl[0]);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're doing a readline in your while condition and again in the body of your while scope, thus skipping 1 readline instruction (in the while condition). try this instead:

```
StreamReader ar = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\arash\Desktop\problem1 (3).in");
string s = ar.ReadLine();
while (s != null)
{
    //string[] spl = s.Split(' ');
    // below code seems safer, blatantly copied from one of the other answers..
    string[] spl = s.Split(' ', 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    MessageBox.Show(spl[0]);
    s = ar.ReadLine();
 }
```

Comment: I was assuming an ideal input here, and the presence of additional spaces in his input list to be nothing but additional formatting he applied for the sake of a nicely readable list, in which case trimming is redundant

Comment: I recant my previous comment as it is probably was just his formatting (however trimming the lines is always a good practice). + 1 by way of apology :)

Comment: that's ok, wild assumptions probably are the root of all evil :-) anyway, I'll edit it for good measure anyway

Answer (score 4):

You are reading a line in the `while` check, and then again to parse the value - which is why it only seems to read the even lines.

Proposed solution:

```
StreamReader ar = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\arash\Desktop\problem1 (3).in");
// Prepare the first line.
string line = ar.ReadLine();
while (line != null) {
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy.aspx
    string[] spl = line.Split(' ', 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    MessageBox.Show(spl[0]);
    // Prepare the next line.
    line = ar.ReadLine();
}
```

**update**: using an overload of `string.Split()` that returns no empty results and max 2 values (1 and the rest of the string).

Comment: This gets my vote for the best solution for good use of *StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries* to solve any formatting issues. I would roll the line = ar.ReadLine() into the while clause though :)

Answer (score 3):

### Try this (streamlined version):

```
    StreamReader ar = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\arash\Desktop\problem1 (3).in");
    while ((string line = ar.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] spl = line.Split(' ', 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        MessageBox.Show(spl[0]);
    }
```

You are reading twice but only using the second read.

Note: You are also not trimming spaces from the start of the lines so you will lose numbers if the data has leading spaces (as shown in the example).

Answer (score 2):

```
    StreamReader ar = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\arash\Desktop\problem1 (3).in");
    // Load a line into s
    string s = ar.ReadLine();
    while (s != null)
    {
        // Split on space
        string[] spl = s.Trim(' ').Split(' ');
        // Declare two variables to hold the numbers
        int one;
        int two;
        // Try to parse the strings into the numbers and display the sum
        if ( int.TryParse( spl[0], out one ) && int.TryParse( spl[1], out two) ) {
            MessageBox.Show( (one + two).ToString() )
        }
        // Error if the parsing failed
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Numbers were not in integer format");
        }
        // Read the next line into s
        s = ar.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: I was sort of assuming they'd be correctly indented (i.e. not indented). But very well.

Comment: @HiTech I'm not sure if the original input has that leading space. The OP claims that 15 was shown, so trimming is not his problem. Not showing `-944` and `540` can be explained by the double `ReadLine()` alone.

Comment: @HiTect I was assuming that was because the OP read twice on each while, thus skipping a line, and also only displaying the first number on each line.

Comment: I recant my previous comment as it is probably was just his formatting (however trimming the lines is always a good practice). +1 by way of apology (and I see you added a trim) :)