# how to get sum of numbers in each lines

Tags: c#

I am just a beginner, and I have a text file like this:

1 2 3 4 5 (they are all in different lines)

how to sum these numbers to get 15 in c#?

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: find them, parse them, add them.

Comment: @waynechen This forum is meant for asking very specific questions about code. Once you have made a start on it, we will help work with you on specific questions. Plus this looks more like a homework assignment. "Teach a man to fish and he will eat for 1,000 years. Give a man some fish and he will starve to death".

Comment: You'll want to use a `System.IO.StreamReader` to read your file, line by line. Start with that, then bring us some code and we'll make it work with you. And here's a link to a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595339/getting-sum-of-numbers-in-each-line-of-file?rq=1

Comment: yes it is a homework, I spent lots of time myself on this, feels like all I need is just a small hint. also, I am new here, is it okay to ask for help with homework ? I won't ask if it is not okay here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put your numbers in file.txt in bin/Debug.
Put this into your Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var nums = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
            var total = 0;
            foreach (var str in nums)
            {
                total += int.Parse(str);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would not work in his case because his text file has 1 number per line, as opposed to having all the number in a string like your sample.